# How to exclude Distribution list results from search

Tags: search, sharepoint, user-profile, rest

I used `/_api/search/query?querytext='${query}'&sourceid='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'` to search the user profile however it is returning results from Distribution list as well.

For example, when I search 'Sydney', I want to return people who have 'Sydney' as location, but it is also returning people who are in a Distribution list called 'Sydney Support'.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You could add some limit querytext like:

```
Location=Sydney
```

Comment: Location is just an example. I could search any properties but want to limit the properties to be just User Profile properties.